# dot dot dot spread operation not working in visual studio code intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using the three-dot spread operator in my javascript projects in vscode. And after some time or probably after an update, visual studio code intelisense keeps blocking typing `...` by popping up other keywords, and adding them in between.

for example on my attempt to write `records.add({...old})`, When I put the first `.` Intelisense pops up like the following

[image: intelisense popping up]

Then when I keep on adding another `.` it types in they word `Promise` or something on the top of the list. And at the end I end up with the following written.

[image: vscode IntelliSense ruining spread operation, three dot, dot dot dot]

As you can see this is very disturbing while coding. I either have to close IntelliSense for every dot I type, or I have to clear the generated keywords. How can this be solved? What is causing this?

My vscode version is `1.59.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This worked for me

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (control + comma)
- Type `editor.suggest.showWords` in the search box
- `Uncheck` the Setting,  (It says `When enabled intellisense shows text-suggestions`)

**Or to disable it specifically for javascript**

Add the line `"editor.suggest.showWords": false` in `settings.json`, inside the `[javascript]` section.

You can open settings.json by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, and typing `settings.json`

For more information on this temporary fix, you can check the github issue on the official vscode repo  [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130096)